# Flume config for Kafka source with ByteArraySerializer

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

Trying to read data from `Kafka` in `Flume`. I have configured all other necessary details for kafka source. The data from `kafka` is using `ByteArraySerializer`.

However  the following configs for serializers doesn't appear to be working,

```
flume.sources.kafka-source.kafka.consumer.key.serializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
flume.sources.kafka-source.kafka.consumer.value.serializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

Is there anything wrong here?

PS: I am a flume newbie

Comment: What are you trying to use Flume to do? What's your target for the data?

Comment: You might be questioning flumes' need here as there is kafka already. But one of the flume's sink is a legacy blackbox module, which cannot read from kafka.

Comment: okay…but if you can give a completely picture of what you're doing, it's easier for people to help :)

Comment: In a Nutshell, data from servers are pushed to `kafka` with `ByteArraySerializer` (Earlier there were no serializers). One of the consumer for kafka is Flume, So from flume I am trying to read the new serialized data. This is where i would need help, I am not able correctly add the serializer property for kafka source in flume config.